# What does ID in label tag do?

Tags: html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label ***id="email-label"*** for="email">Email</label>
  <input
    type="email"
    name="email"
    id="email"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter your Email"
    required
  />
</div>
```

I know that ID in input is needed if you want to refer it by a label and that I understand but in this instance there is an ID in label and i do not know why it is there. I thought they wanted to create an ID so that they can refer it in CSS with "email-label" but I could not find any ID under that name.

Could you please tell me what this email-label in Label do? Thank you!

Comment: Without rest of the code - there it is doing just nothing

Comment: normally you will give many elements id´s with specific names, if you access them in your .css or not is your choice - you can also just delete it, it won´t matter

Comment: So this ID in label is just there to identify it but other than that, it does nothing? Does it have something to do with accessibility features for people with disabilities?

Comment: @Sloth99 - it might. One possibility is that you could have another element reference it with an attribute such as `aria-labelledby='email-label'`, although such usage isn't limited to label elements.

Comment: @Alohci Thank you, although it is not so important, I am trying to understand what he meant by that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would do the same as in other elements, you can access the elment through CSS `#email-label` or JS `getElementById("email-label")`.

Comment: Thank you this was the answer that I was looking for!